# Liaison de verbes en er

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

Si je ne me trompe pas, la chanteuse Zaz semble faire la liaison entre l'infinitif d'un verbe en *er* et la prochaine voyelle. Cela peut s'etendre dans au moins deux chansons :

> Celle [la solitude] que l'on choisit pour **discuter avec** soi
>   
>  — J'aime j'aime ([vidéo](https://youtu.be/r3ZKk08kYXM?t=44), [paroles](https://www.paroles.net/zaz/paroles-j-aime-j-aime))
>
> Comme un fou va **jeter à** la mer
>   
>  — Tous les cris les S.O.S. ([vidéo](https://youtu.be/5VBSaGz0fnc?t=23), [paroles](https://www.paroles.net/daniel-balavoine/paroles-tous-les-cris-les-s-o-s))
>   
> *N.B. Daniel Balavoine ne fait pas la liaison dans sa [version originelle](https://youtu.be/voIINSw_y9Y?t=44)*.

Dans les deux cas on dirait qu'elle prononce /eʁa/ là où on ferait la liaison.

Pour moi c'est bizarre. Est-ce plutôt normal ? Particulier à quelque dialecte ? (Zaz est née à Tours.) Ou n'entends-je pas ce que je crois entendre ?

Comment: Peut-être une réponse [ici](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=MF4SAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=liaison+adjectif+en+er&source=web&ots=9rCefNQlCi&sig=7PH5O5lvZLzV5nFPVk0DBSVrGlM&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q=liaison%20adjectif%20en%20er&f=false)

Comment: Elle est tellement rare qu'on ne m'avait jamais appris à la faire en lecture à voix haute à l'école et que j'ignorais que c'était une possibilité jusqu'à il y a quelques années quand on me l'a décrite comme un phénomène nouveau chez certains journalistes et que j'ai commencé à la remarquer chez quelques journalistes et politiciens, surtout français. Je me méfie d'une "recency illusion" ici, mais il semble quand même que cette liaison bénéficie d'un certain effet de mode chez les professionnels de la langue

Comment: Ceci n'a rien à voir avec la présente question sauf que ça concerne un renseignement que je vous ai donné un jour concernant les liaisons ; il s'agissait des liaisons interdites pour lesquelles existe un autre nom, que je vous avait dit être « mal à propos » ; le nom correct est « mal-t-à-propos » ou encore « maltapropos ».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est une liaison qui est facultative, elle est souvent utilisée en musique, théâtre, poésie (orale), voire des discours, etc.

Elle a une certaine connotation poétique et littéraire, un peu au même titre que les inversions qu'on rencontre surtout en poésie, mais elle n'est pas utilisée dans le langage courant.

Answer (score 3):

Selon l'[Académie française](http://academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#46_strong-em-liaisons-em-strong), cette liaison n'est ni obligatoire ni interdite. On fait donc comme on le souhaite.